# Redirection problem--from Facebook application to Facebook tab

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

I want to redirect from my Facebook app-canvas page to Facebook tab
I'm using PHP 
when I redirect with `header('location':$taburl)` tag it remain at the same canvas page.

Please give me answer of this problem as soon as possible

Comment: Please post the url of your tab as well.

Comment: I have the suspicion that facebook might not allow this.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438814/facebook-iframe-app-strange-redirection-problems

Answer (score 2):

Correct PHP redirect should look like this:

```
header('location:'.$taburl);
```

Now if you are using iframe app it would only redirect your iframe. For full page redirect you would need to use javascript.

Comment: yes that was the problem. When you redirect using normal header location it loads it in iframe and facebook detects that and show only the logo, clicking on the logo redirects to the tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a FBML canvas, you could simply do this:

```
<?php
  echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $taburl . '" />';
?>
```