# Facebook Iframe App - Strange Redirection Problems

Tags: authentication, facebook, iframe

When I'm doing a server-side redirection in a Facebook iframe application, I get the this strange Facebook Logo with a link. When I click it, I get redirected to site I set the redirection to in the first place. What happens here? Any "Click Protection" in place?

Thanks!

Redirection Code:
Tried **Client Redirect**

```
    args = dict(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, redirect_uri=base_dir , scope='user_photos,email,offline_access')
    return render_to_response('fb/nopermission.html', { 'javascript': "<script>window.top.location=\"" + "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?" + urllib.urlencode(args )+ "\"</script>"  } )
```

and **Server Redirect:**

```
args = dict(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, redirect_uri=base_dir , scope='user_photos,email,offline_access')
return HttpResponseRedirect(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?" + urllib.urlencode(args))
```

Same Result in both cases

[image]

Comment: What the URL you're redirecting to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380876/how-to-authorize-facebook-app-using-redirect-in-canvas/3380939#3380939

Comment: @serg555 as you can see... already tried that! :/

Comment: @Henrik so when you do js redirect how does your page url look like (in a browser)?

Comment: Same result (screenshot) with both methods (client & server).

Answer (score 0):

Arrgh! Facebook has such a shitty documentation that I hit upon zillion problems while developing for it.

This one is because you cannot redirect directly from with your app. use a href link and specify the target property to _top or use the javascript

```
window.top.location="redirecturl"
```

to workaround this bug.

Answer (score 0):

For redirection purpose use this code:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.top.location.href = "<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>";
</script>
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>" />
  <meta http-equiv="window-target" content="_top" />
</noscript>
```